# Status of $x^3+y^3+z^3=6xyz$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, rational-points

In

- Erik Dofs, *Solutions of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = nxyz$*, Acta Arithmetica **73** (1995) pp. 201–213, doi:[10.4064/aa-73-3-201-213](https://doi.org/10.4064/aa-73-3-201-213), [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/206818)

the author has studied the Diophantine equation
\begin{equation}
x^3+y^3+z^3=nxyz\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is an integer. I am interested in the specific case $n=6$. The author mentions:

> For a fixed $n$-value, (1) can be transformed into an elliptic curve
> with a recursive solution structure derived by the "chord and tangent
> process".

How does this work for the case $n=6$? Does this generate all or infinitely many solutions? What progress has been made in this specific case?

Comment: This curve has a rational point at $(x:y:z)=(1:2:3)$
(and infinitely many others, such as $(19:21:-52)$ ).
If I did this right it's isomorphic with $Y^2 + Y = X^3 - 54 X - 88$,
which has torsion ${\bf Z} / 3{\bf Z}$ (as usual in this family)
and rank 1, see e.g. <https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/189/b/2>.
So yes, one can start with $(1:2:3)$ and its permutations and generate
all rational solutions with "chords and tangents".

Comment: I am not sure the OP is interested in rational (not integer) solutions.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Can we say anything specific about positive solutions alone?

Comment: But rational solutions to the Weierstrass equation will always correspond to integer solutions of the homogeneous equation in OP’s question, @dodd .

Comment: Usually in this case one is interested in co-prime solutions, @Lubin. Like in the paper linked in the OP.

Comment: @dodd as usual, each rational point on the elliptic curve corresponds to 
a unique primitive solution (up to multiplying $(x,y,z)$ by $-1$).
$$ $$
**Haran**: The positive solutions constitute one of two connected components
of the real locus of the elliptic curve.  Since the generator is on that
component (and the identity is not), its odd multiples again yield
positive solutions.  The next batches of positive solutions are permutations of $(1817, 3258, 5275)$ and $(4904676969, 10840875082, 15051171563)$.

Comment: In the first line of the body of the question, $z^2$ should be $z^3$. (I would just edit this myself, but edits have to be at least ten characters.)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Fixed this now (seems that 9 of the 10 characters can be invisible whitespace ☺)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies and even more characters can be used for human-readable information that might be of use to someone down the track. :-)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thank you for your response! If possible, could you let me know what substitution you made to transform the given Diophantine Equation into an Elliptic Curve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method to transform an arbitrary smooth cubic into a Weierstrass form is standard and is explained for instance in the lovely book by Silverman-Tate, see section 1.3 or appendix B there. It is also implemented in Sage as `EllipticCurve_from_cubic`

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Collecting comments into a community wiki answer.)

There is a standard method for transforming a smooth cubic into Weierstrass form. See for example Section 1.3 or Appendix B of Silverman and Tate's book [Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/RPECHome.html).  It is also implemented in Sage as $\mathtt{EllipticCurve\_from\_cubic}$.

For $n=6$ your curve is isomorphic to $Y^2 + Y = X^3 -54X  - 88$. According to the [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/189/b/2), it has torsion $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and rank 1.  Thus one can start with the obvious solution $(x:y:z) = (1:2:3)$ and its permutations and generate all rational solutions.  Since your equation is homogeneous, finding all rational solutions is equivalent to finding all integer solutions.

The positive solutions constitute one of two connected components of the real locus of the elliptic curve. Since the generator is on that component (and the identity is not), its odd multiples again yield positive solutions. The next batches of positive solutions are permutations of $(1817,3258,5275)$ and $(4904676969, 10840875082, 15051171563)$.

Answer (score 4):

My paper

["Unsolvable cases of $P^3+Q^3+cR^3=d PQR$", *Rocky Mountain J. of Math.* (**28**),No 3, 1998](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-28/issue-3/Unsolvable-Cases-of-P3Q3cR3dPQR/10.1216/rmjm/1181071746.full)

gives 7 (infinite) generic classes of unsolvability of the original equation. However
there are still many (generic) cases to prove!
Solutions have been found for all $n$ in the range $0<n\le1000$.

Comment: "For all n", what do you mean? All d, certain c?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, by 'original equation' I meant x^3+y^3+z^3=nxyz..Also, I should have written *Solutions have been found for all solvable n-cases <=1000.

Answer (score 2):

We show the integer solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3 = nxyz$ using elliptic curve.
$x^3+y^3+z^3 = nxyz\tag{1}$
Let $s=x+y+z$, then equation $(1)$ reduces to
$(-3x+3s+nx)y^2+(-3s^2+6sx+nx^2-3x^2-nxs)y+s^3-3s^2x+3sx^2=0.$
This quadratic in y must have rational solutions, so the discriminant must be square number.
Hence we obtain
$v^2 = (-6n+9+n^2)x^4+(-2n^2s+6sn)x^3+(-18s^2+n^2s^2-6ns^2)x^2+(12s^3+2ns^3)x-3s^4.$
Furthermore, let $U=s/x$ then we obtain

$$V^2 = -3U^4+(12+2n)U^3+(-18-6n+n^2)U^2+(6n-2n^2)U+9+n^2-6n\tag{2}.$$
This quartic equation is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve below.
$$Y^2-2nYX+(-72+12n+4n^2)Y = X^3+(-6n-18)X^2+(108+12n^2-72n)X-1944+216n^2+648n-72n^3\tag{3}$$

$U = \frac{\large{-12n^2+2nX-6X+108}}{\large{Y}}$
$V = \frac{\large{-5832+60n^3X+324n^2X-972nX-8n^3Y+72n^4+3888n-1620X+216Y-3X^3+162X^2-432n^3-18n^2X^2+X^3n}}{\large{Y^2}}$
$X = \frac{\large{-6V+18-12n+2nV+2n^2+6Un-2Un^2}}{\large{U^2}}$
$Y = \frac{\large{-4Un^3+4n^3-12U^2n^2+4n^2V+24Un^2-36n^2-36Un-24nV+108n+108U^2-108+36V}}{\large{U^3}}$

If the rank of elliptic curve $(3)$ is positive, we can obtain the infinitely many rational points.
Hence we obtain the infinitely many integer solutions of equation $(1)$.

The rank and generator are obtainded using mwrank(Cremona).

Example of $n=6$.
Minimal Weierstrass form is $Y^2+Y=X^3-54X-88$.
Rank=1 and generator=$P(-2,3)$.
The rational points $(X,Y)$ of $Y^2+Y=X^3-54X-88$ are obtained by group law using Online Magma Calculator as follows.

```
           P<X>:=PolynomialRing(RationalField());
           E := EllipticCurve([0, 0, 1, -54, -88]);
           P :=E![-2,3];
           2*P;
           3*P;
           4*P;
           5*P
           6*P;
           7*P;
```

The rational points $(X,Y)$ of $Y^2+Y=X^3-54X-88$.
$1P:[   -2,     3]$
$2P:[   40,   248]$
$3P:[-143/36, 1621/216]$
$4P:[56404/5041, 9350169/357911]$
$5P:[-15323534/2505889, 12752626540/3966822287]$
$6P:[3494518273/430479504, -31008773293919/8931588748992]$
$7P:[-43215340027190/7570240479649, -132725251679433577707/20828812647389616143]$
In this way, we can obtain the infinitely many rational points of $Y^2+Y=X^3-54X-88$.

Hence there are infinitely many integer solutions for equation $(1).$
We can get the solutions using group law as follows.

$mP: [    x,      y,      z]$
$1P:[    1,     2,     3]$
$2P:[   52,   -21,   -19]$
$3P:[ 1817,  3258,  5275]$
$4P:[-2847511, 3096807, -124904]$
$5P:[10840875082, 4904676969, 15051171563]$
$6P:[-150777667094725, 458665691607396, -203863624933571]$
$7P:[81821352777652044467, 29381282043563909553, 46875396961726681714]$
The positive solutions are the case of $P,3P,5P,7P$.

We show only some solutions.

```
            [n] [rank] [  x     y     z]
            

            [  3][ ][    1,     1,     1]
            [  5][0][    1,     2,     1]
            [  6][1][    1,     3,     2]
            [  9][1][    3,     7,     2]
            [ 10][1][    5,    18,     7]
            [ 13][1][    9,    38,    13]
            [ 14][1][    2,    13,     7]
            [ 15][1][    7,    -1,    -3]
            [ 16][1][   70,    -9,   -31]
            [ 17][1][    5,    37,    18]
            [ 18][1][   95,    42,    13]
            [ 19][1][    9,     5,     1]
            [ 20][1][   61,   -13,   -14]
            [ 21][1][    2,    21,    13]
            [ 26][1][   91,    38,     9]
            [ 29][1][   43,   182,    27]
            [ 30][1][   31,    21,     2]
            [ 31][1][   37,    -1,   -27]
            [ 35][1][   97,   -14,   -19]
            [ 36][1][  151,    -7,   -78]
            [ 38][1][   70,   629,   151]
            [ 40][1][    9,    -1,    -2]
            [ 41][2][    1,     9,     2]
            [ 44][1][  819,   -19,  -554]
            [ 47][1][  845,   -38,  -367]
            [ 51][1][    9,    77,    13]
            [ 53][1][    2,    27,     7]
            [ 54][1][    2,    57,    43]
            [ 57][1][   91,   310,    19]
            [ 62][1][13559153, -1513300, -1950953]
            [ 63][1][ 3775,  -247,  -903]
            [ 64][1][1338039, -119479, -232736]
            [ 66][1][    3,    14,     1]
            [ 67][1][ 1133, 23517,  7525]
            [ 69][2][    2,    73,    57]
            [ 70][1][1478979, -27083, -896668]
            [ 71][1][   67,    -7,    -9]
            [ 72][1][-404512675962, 5450170263655, -1012930784383]
            [ 73][1][89200900157319, 2848691279889518, 1391526622949983]
            [ 74][1][  133,  4607,  2502]
            [ 76][2][   45,    -2,   -13]
            [ 77][2][   52,    -5,    -7]
            [ 83][1][    5,    61,     9]
            [ 84][1][   56,    -1,   -31]
            [ 86][1][    2,    91,    73]
            [ 87][1][   21,    -1,    -5]
            [ 92][1][-20446843218005, 35661385544981, -548624531286]
            [ 94][2][   19,   945,   746]
            [ 96][1][   38,    -3,    -5]
            [ 98][1][-2559169, 59978401, -14154192]
            [ 99][1][14466072543, -1832602198, -1150522313]
            [101][1][ 1271,  3078,    79]
            [102][1][459338480695732254, 3816006884967068935, 13212742329826830581]
            [103][1][   61,    -4,    -9]
            [103][1][58383, -1159, -26024]
            [105][2][    2,   111,    91]
            [106][2][    1,    54,    35]
            [107][1][-197624310994, 1329876450605, -83341950251]
            [108][1][   39,    -2,    -7]
            [109][1][-99054267227, 7254524660292, -4035385003297]
            [110][1][ 2745, 18578,  1147]
            [112][1][81634675793306734523552997069865, -66756829882613387041310733449793, -403909122691328588518061393542]
            [113][1][345842, 6313383, 15170275]
            [116][1][ 1204,   -13,  -739]
            [117][1][  545, 10318,  1677]
            [119][1][   49,    -1,   -19]
            [120][1][ 8869,  -496, -1317]
            [122][1][25590382918388481967217, 407249928739620845890, 23848086141138276680923]
            [123][1][-45191178833837, 10554611259665663, -8723981310176706]
            [124][1][-1882858151, 4389003335, -75992904]
            [126][2][    2,   133,   111]
            [127][1][  931,   -45,  -151]
            [128][1][1158179, -422318, -23611]
            [129][2][   70,  2361,   629]
            [130][1][16177096946436536530, 639905104499493910311, 1046599292363750394389]
            [132][1][ 2234,   -39,  -905]
            [133][1][691440137111968428652609, 8149000233894575265542178, 27006382877335430051053793]
            [136][2][ 1118,   -45,  -203]
            [142][1][6587432496387235561093636933115859813174, 53881756527432415186060525094013536917351, 222932371699623861287567763383948430761525]
            [143][1][1636453, -1520593, -2435]
            [145][1][157591646586434781, 44634584148027469, 1007950541819512850]
            [147][1][   21,  1529,   925]
            [148][1][1418519131294563, -188778746384314, -71841303293459]
            [149][2][   45,    14,     1]
            [151][2][  133,    -9,   -13]
            [154][2][    2,    63,    13]
            [155][1][466371,  -458, -442729]
            [156][1][-57378032205801587, 151742066509610694, -2433329851945933]
            [158][1][5642215349875, 7336556299898, 80828288788977]
            [159][1][   31,    -1,    -6]
            [160][2][ 3691,   -43, -1764]
            [161][2][   95,    -7,    -8]
            [162][1][   35,  2881,  1854]
            [164][1][-2187625242203395484208435, 9967112990856026231233891, -273965892543545308964986]
            [166][1][  790,   611,     9]
            [167][1][3641058343253213, -868179733296745, -90197542563908]
            [172][1][23593229783585883, -16590668075015195, -127237919517328]
            [174][2][   78,     7,     5]
            [175][1][-12984427575, 55614086497, -1343816497]
            [177][1][11586299300246645065650175011667633294528995894742493608006903, 499128047096078689216614212030144552460525030444760940918765730, 944421945175253160922633489847006529687358187395396664036033027]
            [178][1][    2,    97,    27]
            [181][1][201705586625136962, 10672860536839861, 21088064331923949]
            [185][1][  379,    -4,  -175]
            [186][2][  252,    -5,   -67]
            [187][1][492233837876182300994422946725623025365, -50621375726791887196233101919521352691, -25564297137318411424451907466482829394]
            [189][1][18396,  -209, -7891]
            [190][1][-297115335963207388794859858793856411, 12449186314350611078793751630598133592, -2716813894306138435285959241731689173]
            [191][1][56059, -1399, -11655]
            [192][1][ 3345,   -38, -1417]
            [195][2][    7,   143,    15]
            [196][2][  259,   -18,   -19]
            [197][1][  127, 11655,  6278]
```

Comment: Does your table give, for each $n$, the smallest solution to (1)? The solution you give for $n=177$ is quite large!

Comment: Since solutions are obtained by generators, I guess solutions are smallest for rank=1.
However, it is not always the smallest solution for rank>1.

Answer (score 1):

@Haran enquired about case for $n=6$.

Well lately Seiji Tomita has given a numerical solution for it.

He used the equation below to arrive at a numerical solution:
$$
(m^2+m+1)^3+(m^2-m+1)^3+(2)^3=(m^2+5)(m^2+m+1)(2)(m^2-m+1).
$$

To arrive at $n=6$ we substitute $m=1$. The downside of this is that, when using the above equation one can get only one numerical solution for $n=6$. The equation gives us:
$$
3^3+1^3+2^3=6(3\cdot2\cdot1).
$$
Tomita has given a general method through which solutions for different $n$ can be arrived at. His ["Computational number theory" web page](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/eindex.html) discusses this in [#456. $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = n x y z$](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph448e.html).